# Table view not populating upon view first loading (Swift2 and parse)

Tags: ios, uitableview, parse-platform, swift2

Whenever I run my app, the first time the view containing the tableview loads, the table view does not get populated. But once i switch tabs (i am using a tab bar controller), and then switch back, the table view becomes populated. Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?
Here is the code:

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class NotesViewController: UITableViewController {

var notes = [PFObject]()

var cacheNotes = Bool()

@IBOutlet var showContentTableView: UITableView!

func findNotes() {

    if let user = PFUser.currentUser()?.username! {

        let network = Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork()

        let query = PFQuery(className: "notes")
        query.whereKey("username", equalTo: user)

        if network == true {
            print("connected to network")
        } else {
            ("not connected to network")
            query.fromLocalDatastore()
        }

        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {

                self.notes = objects!

                for object in objects! {
                    if self.cacheNotes == true && network == true {object.pinInBackground()}
                }
            }
        })

    }



    showContentTableView.reloadData()
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()

    if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("cacheNotes") == nil {
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(true, forKey: "cacheNotes")
    }

}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    cacheNotes = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("cacheNotes") as! Bool


    print(cacheNotes)
    findNotes()
    showContentTableView.reloadData()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return notes.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel?.text =  notes[indexPath.row]["title"] as? String

    return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to reload the table inside the closure/block of `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you retrieve data from Parse using `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` the network operation happens in the background, while the rest of the function keeps executing.  So, the `showContentTableView.reloadData()` happens immediately, before the data has been returned.  You need to reload the table data once the network operation has completed, that is, inside the block/closure

```
func findNotes() {
    if let user = PFUser.currentUser()?.username! {

        let network = Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork()

        let query = PFQuery(className: "notes")
        query.whereKey("username", equalTo: user)

        if network == true {
            print("connected to network")
        } else {
            ("not connected to network")
            query.fromLocalDatastore()
        }

        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {

                self.notes = objects!

                showContentTableView.reloadData()

                for object in objects! {
                    if self.cacheNotes == true && network == true {object.pinInBackground()}
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Also, I would suggest that you call `findNotes` from `viewWillAppear` rather than `viewDidAppear` - it will get a head start on populating the data before the table is onscreen.

Comment: I've made the suggested adjustments and it works. Thank you, and thank you for reminding me of the asynchronous blocks within the parse framework.